# What song is playing when Junko demonstrates the brainwashing technique from the anime?

Tags: music, danganronpa

In *Danganronpa 3 - Despair Arc -* episode 8, Junko comes back and kicks Mikan away, which makes her extremely excited. Junko demonstrates to Ryota how she used the techniques she learned from his anime to brainwash Mikan. Ryota tries to run, but Junko threatens to make his classmates participate in the next killing game if he doesn't do what she says.

What song is playing in the background?

Answer (score -1):

The song seems to be the execution music from *Super Dangan Ronpa 2*.